# Hpple parsing HTML with Objective-C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xpath, hpple

I've follow the tutorial from [RayWendErlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) to parse HTML node.

I get the content from an `index.html`.
I've try to use this method to fetch the **background** value.

```
+ (void)parseWithHTMLString:(NSString *)string
{
  NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithData:data isXML:NO];

  NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//div[class='content']/div/div";
  NSArray *nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];
  NSLog(@"%@",nodes);

  NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
  for (TFHppleElement *element in nodes) {
    Model *model = [[Model alloc] init];
    model.colorString = [element objectForKey:@"style"];
    [resultArray addObject:model];
    //NSLog(@"%@",model.colorString);
  }
}
```

**So the question is:**

What I had done wrong?

Comment: What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: And do you get when you run the code you have? We cannot help you if we don't know what's going wrong. I guess you're using the wrong xpath but since you haven't shown us the html code we cannot help you there.

Comment: Have you tried `model.colorString = [element.attributes objectForKey:@"style"];`

Comment: @HAS Try right now, nothing. And I print the `nodes` variable, which console return `Nodes  was nil` to me. Maybe it is issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 small errors in your code.

1. The xPath you used is not correct. You're missing an `@` in front of `class`.
2. The `background` key is an attribute, so you need to ask the `TFHppleElement` for its `attributes` property (which is a dictionary) and get its value via `objectForKey:`.

This is the final code:

```
NSArray *nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@class='content']/div/div"];

for (TFHppleElement *element in nodes) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[element.attributes objectForKey:@"style"]);
}
```

The console output is:

> background: #D93D59
>   background: #E7923D
>   background: #768479
>   background: #EBBA95
>   background: #E26967
>   background: #BF343F
>   background: #254159
>   background: #F2F2F2
>   background: #D9A577
>   background: #BF8969
>   background: #04000D
>   ...